# Is there a Windows Performance Counter which contains the "Log Send Rate" for Availability Groups?

Tags: sql-server, performance, availability-groups, dmv

I wish to be able to get the **"Log Send Rate kb/s"**, as per the SSMS AG dashboard (which is also available via `log_send_rate` column on the DMV [`sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877972.aspx))

I'd like to get it as a Windows Performance Counter... looking at the available counters for the Database Replica category, the nearest is "Log Bytes Received/sec", which doesn't appear to report the same value.

Does anyone know if there is a performance counter or will I need to rely on the DMV?

Answer (score 1):

The DMV column `log_send_rate` will tell you `Rate at which log records are being sent to the secondary databases, in kilobytes (KB)/second.`

Depending on what SP + CU you are running, you may want to look into - [KB 3012182 FIX: Log_Send_Rate column cannot reflect the rate accurately in SQL Server 2012 or in SQL Server 2014](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3012182)

Below [PERFMON counter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878472.aspx) will tell you `how many bytes were sent`

> **SQL Server:Availability Replica --> Bytes Sent to Replica/sec**
>
> Number of bytes sent to the remote availability replica per second. On the primary replica this is the number of bytes sent to the secondary replica. On the secondary replica this is the number of bytes sent to the primary replica.

Comment: This is still not quite the same as the Log Send Rate kb/s as reported per database on the SSMS and as queryable via the DMV on the secondary. I would like a performance counter (which I can sample on the secondary replica) to give the same value as the log_send_rate in the sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states table.